# Trying to find a reference to the manual but can't

Tags: ruby, windows, documentation, rdoc, ri

Simple question, what is the best way on windows to search the documentation. This time I was wanting information on 'while'(resolved now by google) but I still can't can't get ri or the chm documentation on windows to give a result to while.

If I type in the Keyword in search in the chm it doesn't return 'while' it returns many results but not 'while' same for index search.

so In installed ri.

```
>rdoc --all --ri
```

but if I search while

```
C:\Ruby193\bin>ri 'while'
Nothing known about .while
```

I would like to read from the official results. Whats the best?

Also tried ri interactive but same result.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\renshaw>ri -i

Enter the method name you want to look up.
You can use tab to autocomplete.
Enter a blank line to exit.

>> while
Nothing known about .while
>>
```

Comment: well, I use the ruby docs extension for chrome but that's a different approach to the problem...

Comment: i bet there is some addon for ff as well.

Comment: ff has a rails extension for firebug but nothing yet for ri or rdoc

Comment: after some searching you can add rdoc as a search engine in firefox http://ruby-doc.org/docbar/

Comment: To the users who voted to close this question, if you had bothered to read it, you would understand that it is not "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource."  It's asking how to get the `ri` tool to display documentation on core Ruby methods.  Also, what's the point in closing a question four years after it's already been answered?  Don't you guys have anything better to do?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `ri` gives you information about methods, and not language syntax. `while` is Ruby's keyword, just like `begin`. If you try you won't find anything about `begin` in `ri`. Instead you can try `ri File::read` for example.

Comment: so how do I search then for 'while' 'if' 'push' 'pop' etc. in Ruby if ri doesn't assist.

Comment: `while` and `if` aren't methods. Grab the Pickaxe[1] to learn about syntax. Push and pop are Array's methods, so try `ri "Array::push"`.
[1] - http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Comment: For online documentation I recommend http://apidock.com/ruby and http://ruby-doc.org/

Comment: I really like apidock very nice. I ended up finding while in rdoc need to search under keywords in rdoc, would be good if ri could search keywords. Here it was http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby core language keywords and topics, use the `ruby:` prefix.

If you ran `ri ruby:while`, you would get a list of pages.  In that list is `syntax/control_expressions.rdoc`, which probably contains the information that you want.

```
ri ruby:control_expressions
```

Gives you the documentation for core Ruby control expressions (which includes `while`).